# no way of knowing whether or not the receiver has correctly received the last piece of transmitted data when checksum is corrupted?

Tags: tcp

I was reading a text book which shows a simple reliable data transfer service that is similiar to TCP:

[image]

[image]

And the author said:

***Protocol rdt2.0 may look as if it works but, unfortunately, it has a fatal flaw.
In particular, we haven’t accounted for the possibility that the ACK or NAK packet
could be corrupted. Minimally, we will need to add checksum bits to ACK/NAK packets in order to detect such errors. The more difficult question is how the protocol should recover from errors in ACK or NAK packets. The difficulty here is that if an ACK or NAK is corrupted, the sender has no way of knowing whether or not the receiver has correctly received the last piece of transmitted data.***

I'm a little bit confused here, let's say the receiver send an ack packet, an if this packet gets corrupted then it becomes nak packet, when the sender receives this packet(showed as nak) and the sender analyses the checksum and found it was corrupted, then the sender immediately know that it just needs to reverse the nak to ack, which means the sender does know whether or not the receiver has correctly received the last piece of transmitted data?

Comment: "_then the sender immediately know that it just needs to reverse the nak to ack, which means the sender does know whether or not the receiver has correctly received the last piece of transmitted data?_" How do you know the corruption is from NAK to ACK? It could be in some other field. Unfortunately, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if this packet gets corrupted then it becomes nak packet

This is where you're confused.  The packet doesn't become a NAK packet, it gets thrown away because it is corrupted.  A NAK is a positive indication that there's a problem, which is not the same as a corrupted packet.

Here's an analogy:

You ask me "did you get my message?"

If I answer "No," that's an NAK.

If I don't answer, or answer in gibberish, that's the case of a corrupted packet -- you don't get an answer to your question.  Now what do you do?